# ASP.NET 3.5: Is there a distinct advantage to having debug=true in a production environment?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

All answers point to "no!".  However, some people say having debugging enabled is convenient when errors occur on the server.  I am not sure what they mean by this.  Do people actually debug live server code?  I honestly didn't even know you could.  With the website I work on, we use ELMAH for error reporting.  When a server error occurs, we are emailed a complete stack trace.  After acquiring a rough idea of where and how the error occurred, I will open the local solution containing all the code that's currently deployed to the production environment and debug locally.  I never actually debug the code on the server itself, so I am not sure what people mean by that.

I ask this because I just found out today while consolidating web.config XML that debug=true exists on in the staging and production environments' web.config files.  It must have been this way for a few years now and I am wondering what benefits we will experience by turning it off.  Could anything possibly depend on debugging being turned on that might break if shut off after being enabled for over two years since the beginning of the project?

Comment: You might also be interested in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx) in case you get into discussions with people who do think it's a good idea.  He basically runs the teams that built all of this stuff so worth heeding the advice.  He also links to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/04/13/575364.aspx) blog post that goes into  bit more detail of why it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "advantage" that people are talking about is that when an error occurs on the site, the default asp.net error page will show you the actual line of code that failed. If you have debug=false, then you will not see any of that information. I think most who would recommend something like this either do not know about logging frameworks like ELMAH (and hence, cannot easily find the cause of errors on the site without this), or they have left it on the production machine in the beginning of the project while they are installing/testing the site, and then forgot to change it later.

However, with a proper logging framework in place, you can still get good error information behind the scenes without presenting it to your end-users in that way. In fact, you don't want to show that kind of information to end-users because a) they won't know what it means, and b) it could be a possible security issue if sensitive aspects of your code are shown (info that might help somebody find vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to turn it off, and you should get a slight performance boost. It sounds like you are doing the right thing using ELMAH. I cannot think of a good reason why you would want to have it turned ON in production... hope that helps.

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is what people mean when they say having it turned on in the production environment offers convenience in the event that an error occurs on the site.  Does such a convenience exist?  If so, then technically there would be at least some advantage to having it turned on, although at the cost of performance.

Comment: @user701346: My guess would be they say it because it would let you attach a debugger to the application deployed to production.  However, if you ever find yourself going "man....I wish I could attach to production" something has gone horribly horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All the `System.Diagnostic` library is depend from this flag. If you do not use any of this function, then probably you can not see any direct effect, but for see other effect and messages that come from debug functions you need to monitor at lease the windows log file.

Functions like `Debug.Assert`, and `Debug.Fail` are still active if you do not set the debug flag to off, and affect performance, and maybe create small issues that you never see if you do not check the windows system log file.

In our library that they are full with assert, the debug flag are critical.

Also with Debug flag to on, probably the compiler is not make optimization's that also affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Either an advantage or disadvantage depending on how you look at it is that Webresource.axd type files are not cached when `debug="true"`. You've got the advantage of having the latest files every time and a disadvantage of having the latest files every time.

This is often true with other third party compression/combining type modules due to the fact that it is easier to debug non minified javascript etc so they usually only begin properly function once debug is disabled.